# Witchblade - Origin?

Tags: tv, witchblade

I just watched the series of 'Witchblade' but have only read a few of the comics -- In one episode it mentioned the origin being a branch ripped off the Tree of Knowledge of Good and Evil. Was that from the comic or was that simply added for the TV series?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I know, this is something created entirely for the TV show. There were numerous major changes introduced throughout the show's two seasons, with only the core characters and plots remaining intact.

In the comics, the Witchblade is one of several sentient artifacts that have existed since before mankind. Each artifact represents an aspect of the universe. The Witchblade itself represents balance, and is the offspring of The Angelus (representing "light/order") and The Darkness (representing "darkness/chaos"), which are the two most primal forces in creation.

Many, if not all, of the aspect artifacts require a human host or wielder as they cannot influence the world otherwise. The Witchblade is no different, but unlike many of the artifacts it can consciously "choose" or reject its host based on unknown qualities (but bloodline does seem to be a factor).

UPDATE: As promised, here's a pic of the artifacts & their bearers. This is from Top Cow's "Artifacts" series and can be found at the link below the image:
[image: Witchblade: Artifacts]

http://www.comicvine.com/the-13-artifacts/4015-55685/

Comment: You appear to be right - I searched online and found only this reference http://gallica.bnf.fr/VisuSNE?id=oai_avecomics.com_4261&r=&lang=FR "According to one of the TV episodes, the Witchblade was made out of a branch from the Tree of the Knowledge of Good and Evil"

Comment: There's a cool graphic showing the artifacts - I'll add it later. At the moment I'm at work and a Google image search for Witchblade is close to NSFW.